# Nested merging of JSON Objects in Javascript / NodeJS

Tags: sql, json, node.js, merge

I have two SQL Queries that return their data as JSON using NodeJS Seriate.

First is categories with two fields, category and name.

```
     categories = [{ category: '1', name: 'category1' },
     { category: '2', name: 'category2' }]
```

Second one is branches with three fields, category, branch and branchName.

```
     branches = [{ category: '1', branch: '1', name: 'branch1' },
     { category: '1', branch: '2', name: 'branch2' },
     { category: '2', branch: '3', name: 'branch3' },
     { category: '2', branch: '4', name: 'branch4' }]
```

I want to create one merged JSON, based on the category of each JSON that would have the following structure:

```
     all = [
           { category: '1', name: 'category1', 
                 branches: [
                           {branch: '1', name: 'branch1' },
                           {branch: '2', name: 'branch2' }],
            { category: '2', name: 'category2',
                 branches: [
                           {branch: '3', name: 'branch3'},
                           {branch: '4', name: 'branch4'}]
           ]
```

I searched and found several methods of joining or extending two json objects but nothing similar to that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
categories.forEach(function(c) {
  c.branches = branches.filter(function(b) {
      var tmp = b.category;
      delete b.category;
      return tmp === c.category;
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am now facing the issue that only the first category gets branches, it seems that after the "delete d.category" it cannot filter anymore. I commented the "delete b.category" statement and it populates ok, only it reserves the redundant category in branches element.